# ¿Por qué Angular muestra mal la fecha al usar el pipe | date:'fullDate'?

Tags: angular

Tengo una app en Angular que se conecta con un servicio Back con SpringBoot, el servicio backend devuelve una lista de datos de acuerdo a dos parametros que le llegan desde el frontend, la cuestion es que el servicio bakend devuelve datos de fecha de la siguiente manera:

**2021-10-07 00:00:00.0**

y yo muestro esa fecha de la siguiente manera:

```
<td class="centrado">{{consultarDatos.fechaIngreso | date:'fullDate'}}</td>
```

y en pantalla muestra **miércoles, 6 de octubre de 2021**, cuando deberia ser 7, asi como me la manda el back, que esta mal? o como puedo modificarlo para que se pinte correctamente la fecha?

Comment: Si puedes modificar el backend es más rápido quitar la hora de la fecha.

Comment: y como se quita? mi tipo de dato es Date?

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes en el huso horario, si por ejemplo tienes configurado el front para estar a -3 horas, pues el interpreta que sigues estando en en el día 6. Pinta las horas también por pantalla y te darás cuenta si el error viene por aquí.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un método en tu clase con moment.js para darle el formato que deseas a tu fecha. Para consultar como utilizarlo en Angular [aquí puedes hacerlo](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/) e igual te dejo un ejemplo que espero te sirva.

```
import moment from "moment";

formatDate(date:string){
    moment.locale('es');
    if (moment(date).isValid()) {
      return moment(date).format('MMM DD/yyyy').replace('.', '');
    } else {
      return 'invalid-date';
    }
  }

this.formatDate('2021-10-07 00:00:00.0');
```